# How do you use pip to install Pygame/Pygame Zero with Command Prompt?

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

I tried using pip to install Pygame/Pygame Zero via Command Prompt, but it didn't work as expected. Here's what happened.

So basically, I tried using the command `python -m pip install -U pip` but it didn't work as expected. I received a message saying:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

I realized this would be useless, as I already downloaded pip with Python.

Then what I tried to do was use the commands `pip install pygame` and `pip install pgzero` but that didn't work either. Both commands resolved to this:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to add python to PATH too

Comment: try    python3 -m pip install -U pip

Comment: Have you installed Python as the message suggests to do? If `pip` isn’t installed, how are you expecting to use `pip` to install it…?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: @esqew Sorry, I didn't phrase the question correctly. I actually meant how do I use pip to install Pygame and Pygame Zero, because I already downloaded pip with Python. This issue will be fixed.

Comment: @MuneebAhmadKhurram Unfortunately, I don't know what the heck is "easy_install" and, as I said 25 minutes ago, I didn't phrase the question correctly. So, sorry, but no, this does not help me answer my question.

Comment: @BugsAreNasty I think you have now properly phrased your question. Please first add Python to PATH, and then do `python3 -m pip install pygame --user` and that should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Pip automatically comes when downloading Python.
[It can be dowloaded using this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

After installing Python, you can check if pip is installed by entering 'pip' in your command prompt.

If you receive the same message as before, use this command:

```
py -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Let me know if you need any more help !

> Following your update:

I would suggest consulting this [link](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) to get started using Pygame. It says to use: `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user` My personal suggestion would be to start learning Python before goin straight into a library like Pygame. You should start from the basic with tutorials on Youtube.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't phrase the question correctly. Please check the question again. I meant that pip was already downloaded, I just couldn't get to download Pygame/Pygame Zero. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What is the command you are using to install Pygame ?  
I would suggest consulting this https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted to get started using Pygame. It says to use:  
`python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`  
My personal suggestion would be to start learning Python before goin straight into a library like Pygame. You should start from the basic with tutorials on Youtube.
@BugsAreNasty

Comment: OP rephrased their question and changed what was being asked. This answer works for the original (poorly phrased) question. Maybe update the answer or delete it, since it no longer applies after OP's update.